# Get colors around text from bounding box from image in android

Tags: java, android, opencv, opengl-es, rajawali

I have an image consisting of background image with multiple colors and text on it.

I have done OCR and i have recognised the text and bounding box surrounding the text.

Now i want to get all the pixels surrounding the text inside the bounding box and store it in a matrix.

I am using opencv for image processing and opengl for rendering (Rajawali).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [submat](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#submat(org.opencv.core.Rect)) method

Comment: @Miki will it give me the desired result ? But still i ll have a look at it.Thanks.

Comment: Is your end purpose rebuilding the original image, which was messed by a text typed above it?

Comment: Yes . I am taking the original image and drawing a rectangle on top of it where original text was there and i want to replace it with a new text but the background colours behind the text should be the same.
I want to build exactly like this. Have a look :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2OfQdYrHRs